# The contents of an overfull \[ \] environment affects if my document runs, when combined with custom command

Tags: errors, package-writing

I made a `.sty` file like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{printready}[2017/04/19 Defines "ready" and "notready"]

%%%
\newif\if@ready

\DeclareOption{ready}{%
    \@readytrue%
    }

\ProcessOptions\relax

\def\ready#1{%
    \if@ready
        #1
    \else
        \fbox{Here goes a picture}
    \fi
    }
\def\notready#1{%
    \if@ready
        {\PackageError{printready}{Custom error message}{Custom error text}}
    \else
        \fbox{Here will be a picture; It's not ready yet.}
    \fi
    }

\endinput
```

It defines the commands `\ready` and `\notready`. How these will behave depends on wether or not the option `ready` is loaded with the package.

Now consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
  \usepackage[ready]{printready}% Ready option activated

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}I found that this must mean that
%%% Let's call this Equation 1
\[waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy toooooooooooooooooooooo loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong\]
%
%%% Let's call this Equation 2
\[p= \frac{2q}{2-q}(1-2g) \implies p(2-q)=2q(1-2g) \implies p|2q(1-2g) \implies p \leq 2q(1-2g).\]  

\begin{figure}[htbp]\centering
\notready%
    {%
Picture1
    }\caption{caption}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

If I only typ Equation 1 (and not Equation 2), then everything behaves as expected, i.e: I see my custom error message apear.

If I typ Equation 2, then the most unusual thing happens: My run just stops, without showing **any** error message. The last lines of the Console Output (in TeXWorks) are

`Overfull \hbox (4.37506pt too wide) detected at line 11
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 p \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = [](1 \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10`

Nothing happens after this.

What's even stranger is that leaving out the final `g).` from Equation 2 (and thus preventing an overfull `\hbox`) **does** behaves as expected.

How can the contents of `\[  \]` influence the run of my document in this way?

N.B. The error only happens if Equation 2 and `\notready` are used together, whilst the option `ready` is loaded. Otherwise everything goes as expected.

Comment: Do you run LaTeX in interaction mode? In this case the `\PackageError` in `\notready` will wait for interaction until it continues. If you are using an editor, check the settings. It should use, e.g., `--interaction=nonstopmode` or `--interaction=batchmode`as an option to `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I have no Idea. I'm using TeXWorks and selected pdfLaTeX to compile.

Comment: @Schweinebacke But do note that `\PackageError` does what it should, if Equation 2 is not used or shortend.

Comment: TeXWorks opens a input line below the terminal output when an error occures. Type `h` `RETURN` to see the possible inputs you can do. Or type only `RETURN` to continue the LaTeX run.

Comment: @Schweinebacke When I type `h` `<return>` it shows `Custom error text`.  So that is comming from `\notready`. However `Custom error message` is never shown. Typing only `<return>` completes the LaTeX run.

Comment: Completing the LaTeX run is not what I'm interested in however. The `\notready` command is really about the custom error message/text

Comment: You will get a valid result only after completing the LaTeX run. Without the PDF will be corrupt and cannot be shown. So you should always be interested in completing the LaTeX run. And you will see `Custom error message` only after typing `h` `<RETURN>`.

Comment: I get this, if I run your example: [click for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT4qh.png). On the other hand, I see no reason for issuing an error rather than a warning.

Comment: @egreg That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @gebruiker Well, that's not the main point, which is that I can't reproduce the behavior. Can you scroll down the console window?

Comment: @egreg No. The lines I pasted in the OP are the bottom lines.

Comment: @gebruiker What OS are you using? What version of TeXworks?

Comment: @egreg Windows 10. MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit.